# Rails 3: Nested Attribute presence validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 Deeply nested attraibutes:

`Process` has many `categories`,
`Categories` has many `Blocks`

How do i place validate_presence_of calls so when a user is creating a new process and attempts to create a category within it without a definition lets say, that he is redirected to the process edit form and told definition can not be left empty empty?

DO i place the validation in process model or category model?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validations always go on to the model they are validating. Rails will handle the nesting.